# flutter problem: Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.7.10) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.6.10)

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.7.10) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.6.10)

Here i am using latest kotlin version after using this then I got some issue, so how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and I solved it by upgrading the plugin :

```
Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates -> Check for updates now
```

There's an issue in [Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62697211?pli=1) that prevents it from loading the updated version of the Kotlin plugin. Go to plugins then uninstall kotlin then restart ide then once the android studio is back up drop-down tools then select kotlin then configure updates, it should be checking for new updates.

hope it will help!

Comment: I checked It's shwoing You have latest verion of the plugin installed

Comment: I have added some more explanation please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solution for this Issue.
You have to Install the latest version of kotlin Manually.
Goto
1 : "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\plugins"
If you cant see these folders..(Show hidden folders from view tab)
... Here you will see Kotlin folder..
2: Just delete it(Close all the programs using it before deleting).
3: goto kotlin Official website and download the latest version[here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html)
4:Copy the downloaded folder and Paste it in the same directory...

Restart your Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If building gradle differs from one bundled into the IDE plugin

⛔ Problem

```
is the IDE uses the oldest version and you code asking about newest version
```

✅ Solution

```
got to Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates > Update Kotlin version (Install)
```

[image]